# Django CMS - DIVIO LogEntry add instance / Latest files added to the CMS

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-cms

I need to show at my Homepage a list with all the files added/changed as Bootstrap Filer plugin to my Django CMS project. I was using the LogEntry model, but it doesn't save Add actions to LogEntry instances. What I need is something like that:

Latest Changes:

- May 30, 2017 - Test.pdf
- May 28, 2017 - Application Form.pdf
- May 26, 2017 - Brooker.pdf

My problem is that the Add's actions are not saved at LogEntry model... Every time I add, for example, Bootstrap Filer Plugin and add a PDF it doesn't save a new Entry instance of it, only when I delete it. How do I change the default behavior to save Plugin's Add Actions (specially Bootstrap Filer File) at LogEntry Models?

The website is a platform to help insurance brokers to sell. The prices of different companies changes on monthly basis. And every time a new Price table change I need to show in a Latest changes / updates section.

My models.py

```
poll = list(LogEntry.objects.all())

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.poll)
```

My template:

```
    <ul>
    {% for poll in instance.poll %}
      {% if poll.content_type_id == 54 %} <!-- Bootstrap Files Plugin Content Type -->
        <li>
          {{poll.action_time.date }} - {{ poll.object_repr }} - {{ poll.object_repr }}
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
   </ul>
```

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the [Bootstrap3FilePlugin model](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-bootstrap3/blob/1.2.2/aldryn_bootstrap3/models.py#L1193-L1238) suits your needs but you'd like to change its behaviour, the best thing to do is to *subclass* it.

It will be something like this:

- Create a module of your own containing the new code.
- Subclass the plugin model

  ```
  from aldryn_bootstrap3.models import Bootstrap3FilePlugin

      class MyNewBootstrap3FilePlugin(Bootstrap3FilePlugin):
      ...
  ```
- Add a new field, for example:

  ```
  last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  ```

  See the [DateTimeField/DateField reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#datefield).
- You will also need to subclass the [Bootstrap3FileCMSPlugin plugin class](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-bootstrap3/blob/1.2.2/aldryn_bootstrap3/cms_plugins.py#L1077-L1107) to point at a new template:

  ```
  render_template = <whatever>
  ```

  that will display the new `last_updated` field.

Comment: I don't need to change its behavior, I need to list all the add and update actions with Bootstrap3FilePlugin that Editors made at the CMS no matter in which page it was.

Comment: The reason I say you need to change its behaviour is that the behaviour of plugins is to create a LogEntry for delete actions, but not create actions, and you need to know when the plugin was created. The easiest way to do this seems to be to create a version of the plugin class that saves a timestamp, which will contain that information.